# Pytransitions: How can we accomplish a statemachine which posses the features of Hierarchical Machine and AsyncMachine in a single state machine?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, state-machine, hierarchical, pytransitions

I want to build a stat machine such that it can posses features of both HierarchicalMachine and AsyncMachine. I tried this code but Hierarchical and Async are not working simultaneously.

`

```
from transitions.extensions.markup import MarkupMachine
from transitions.extensions.factory import HierarchicalMachine
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
QUEUED = False

class Unhealthy(HierarchicalMachine, AsyncMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        states = [{"name":'aborted', "on_enter":[]},
                    {"name":'clearancetimeouterr', "on_enter":[]},
                    {"name":"awaitingclearanceerr", 'on_enter':[]},
                    {"name":"cleared", 'on_enter':[]}
                    ]
        transitions = [{"trigger":"abort", "source":"aborted", "dest":"awaitingclearanceerr"},
                        {"trigger":"awaitingclearanceerr", "source":"clearancetimeout", "dest":"awaitingclearanceerr"},
                        {"trigger":"cleared", "source":"awaitingclearanceerr", "dest":"cleared"}]
        super().__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="awaitingclearanceerr", queued=QUEUED)
        

class Healthy(HierarchicalMachine, AsyncMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        unhealthy = Unhealthy()
        states = [{"name":'idle', 'on_enter':[]},
                    {"name":"busy", 'on_enter':[]},
                    {"name":"done", 'on_enter':[]}]

        transitions = [{'trigger':'start', 'source':'idle', 'dest':'busy'},
                        {"trigger":"done", "source":"busy", "dest":"done"},
                        {"trigger":"idle", "source":"awaiting_clearance", "dest":"idle"}]
        super().__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="idle", queued=QUEUED)



class StateMachine(HierarchicalMachine, MarkupMachine, AsyncMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        unhealthy= Unhealthy()
        healthy = Healthy()
        states = [{'name':"idle"}, {"name":'healthy', 'children':healthy}, {"name":"unhealthy", "children":unhealthy}]
        super().__init__(states=states, initial="idle", queued=QUEUED)
        self.add_transition("start_machine", "idle", "healthy")
        self.add_transition('abort', 'healthy', 'unhealthy')
```

`I want something like that but HierarchicalMachine and AsyncMachine are not working together. And giving the following error:`RuntimeError: AsyncMachine should not call `Machine._process`. Use `Machine._process_async` instead.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [extensions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#-extensions) section of `transitions` documentation mentions the following:

> There are two mechanisms to retrieve a state machine instance with the desired features enabled. The first approach makes use of the convenience factory with the four parameters graph, nested, locked or asyncio set to `True` if the feature is required.

```py
from transitions.extensions import MachineFactory

AsyncHSM = MachineFactory.get_predefined(nested=True, asyncio=True)

machine = AsyncHSM(states=['A', 'B'], ...)

class MyHSM(ASyncHSM):
   ...
```

> This approach targets experimental use since in this case the underlying classes do not have to be known.
> However, classes can also be directly imported from `transitions.extensions`. The naming scheme is as follows:

|  | Diagrams | Nested | Locked | Asyncio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Machine | ✘ | ✘ | ✘ | ✘ |
| GraphMachine | ✓ | ✘ | ✘ | ✘ |
| HierarchicalMachine | ✘ | ✓ | ✘ | ✘ |
| LockedMachine | ✘ | ✘ | ✓ | ✘ |
| HierarchicalGraphMachine | ✓ | ✓ | ✘ | ✘ |
| LockedGraphMachine | ✓ | ✘ | ✓ | ✘ |
| LockedHierarchicalMachine | ✘ | ✓ | ✓ | ✘ |
| LockedHierarchicalGraphMachine | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✘ |
| AsyncMachine | ✘ | ✘ | ✘ | ✓ |
| AsyncGraphMachine | ✓ | ✘ | ✘ | ✓ |
| HierarchicalAsyncMachine | ✘ | ✓ | ✘ | ✓ |
| HierarchicalAsyncGraphMachine | ✓ | ✓ | ✘ | ✓ |

So I guess this is what you are looking for:

```py
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalAsyncMachine
# in case you want markup/graphviz support
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalAsyncGraphMachine
```

In case you want to 'mix' your own machine class, have a look at [factory.py](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/blob/21f6bd3142a35229d738474d09057e4ce5e4f0f4/transitions/extensions/factory.py) to get an idea about how the subclasses are defined. Pay attention to the order of inheritance. Mixing this up might cause undesired effects.